# Characterization of $\Delta^0_0$ (rudimentary) functions

Tags: logic, computability, recursion

A $\Delta^0_0$, or rudimentary, functions $\Bbb N^k \rightarrow \Bbb N$ is a function whose graph is definable by a bounded formula.  Can this class of functions characterized by means of closure conditions, rate of growth, or other (non-syntactic) conditions?

I looked at Odifreddi's Volume II but it was not very helpful.  I don't have access to books on bounded arithmetic now.

Comment: If my memory serves me right, every total recursive function is dominated everywhere by a $\Delta_0$ function. So there are non-PR functions in this class. In particular you can't quite control the growth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in this answer https://mathoverflow.net/a/198434, the class is equal to the entire linear time hierarchy in computational complexity theory.  Also, it can be characterized by closure property: it's the smallest class containing the initial functions, subtraction and multiplication, closed under composition and bounded minimization, as explained in *Rudimantary relation and primitive recursion: A toolbox* by Esbelin and More.